# MATLAB to Scilab conversion: mfile2sci error "File contains no instruction"

Tags: matlab, scilab, converters

I am *very* new to Scilab, but so far have not been able to find an answer (either here or via google) to my question. I'm sure it's a simple solution, but I'm at a loss. I have a lot of MATLAB scripts I wrote in grad school, but now that I'm out of school, I no longer have access to MATLAB (and can't justify the cost). Scilab looked like the best open alternative. I'm trying to convert my .m files to Scilab compatible versions using `mfile2sci`, but when running the `mfile2sci` GUI, I get the error/message shown below. Attached is the original code from the M-file, in case it's relevant.

I Searched Stack Overflow and companion sites, Google, Scilab documentation.

The M-file code follows (it's a super basic MATLAB script as part of an old homework question -- I chose it as it's the shortest, most straightforward M-file I had):

```matlab
Mmax = 15;
N = 20;
T = 2000;
%define upper limit for sparsity of signal
smax = 15;
mNE = zeros(smax,Mmax);
mESR= zeros(smax,Mmax);
for M = 1:Mmax
    aNormErr = zeros(smax,1);
    aSz = zeros(smax,1);
    ESR = zeros(smax,1);
for s=1:smax % for-loop to loop script smax times
    normErr = zeros(1,T); 
    vESR = zeros(1,T);
    sz = zeros(1,T);
    for t=1:T %for-loop to carry out 2000 trials per s-value
        esr = 0;
        A = randn(M,N); % generate random MxN matrix
        [M,N] = size(A);
        An = zeros(M,N);            % initialize normalized matrix
            for h = 1:size(A,2) % normalize columns of matrix A
                V = A(:,h)/norm(A(:,h));
                An(:,h) = V;
            end
        A = An; % replace A with its column-normalized counterpart
        c = randperm(N,s); % create random support vector with s entries
        x = zeros(N,1);    % initialize vector x
            for i = 1:size(c,2)
                val = (10-1)*rand + 1;% generate interval [1,10]
                neg = mod(randi(10),2); % include [-10,-1]
                    if neg~=0
                        val = -1*val;
                    end
                x(c(i)) = val; %replace c(i)th value of x with the nonzero value
            end
            y = A*x; % generate measurement vector (y)
            R = y;  
            S = []; % initialize array to store selected columns of A
            indx = []; % vector to store indices of selected columns
            coeff = zeros(1,s); % vector to store coefficients of approx.
            stop = 10; % init. stop condition
            in = 0; % index variable
            esr = 0;
            xhat = zeros(N,1); % intialize estimated x signal
            while (stop>0.5 && size(S,2)<smax)
                %MAX = abs(A(:,1)'*R);
                maxV = zeros(1,N);
                for i = 1:size(A,2)
                    maxV(i) = abs(A(:,i)'*R);
                end
                in = find(maxV == max(maxV));
                indx = [indx in];
                S = [S A(:,in)];
                coeff = [coeff R'*S(:,size(S,2))]; % update coefficient vector
                for w=1:size(S,2)
                    r = y - ((R'*S(:,w))*S(:,w)); % update residuals
                    if norm(r)<norm(R)
                        index = w;
                    end
                    R = r;
                stop = norm(R); % update stop condition
                end
        
                for j=1:size(S,2) % place coefficients into xhat at correct indices
                    xhat(indx(j))=coeff(j);
                end
            nE = norm(x-xhat)/norm(x); % calculate normalized error for this estimate
            %esr = 0;
            indx = sort(indx);
            c = sort(c);
                if isequal(indx,c)
                    esr = esr+1;
                end
            end
        vESR(t) = esr;    
        sz(t) = size(S,2);
        normErr(t) = nE;
    end

    %avsz = sum(sz)/T;
    aSz(s) = sum(sz)/T;
    %aESR = sum(vESR)/T;
    ESR(s) = sum(vESR)/T;
    %avnormErr = sum(normErr)/T; % produce average normalized error for these run
    aNormErr(s) = sum(normErr)/T; % add new avnormErr to vector of all av norm errors
end
% just put this here to view the vector
mNE(:,M) = aNormErr;
mESR(:,M) = ESR;
% had an 'end' placed here, might've been unmatched
mNE%reshape(mNE,[],Mmax)
mESR%reshape(mESR,[],Mmax)]
figure
dimx = [1 Mmax];
dimy = [1 smax];
imagesc(dimx,dimy,mESR)
colormap gray
strESR = sprintf('Average ESR, N=%d',N);
title(strESR);
xlabel('M');
ylabel('s');
strNE = sprintf('Average Normed Error, N=%d',N);
figure
imagesc(dimx,dimy,mNE)
colormap gray
title(strNE)
xlabel('M');
ylabel('s');
```

The command used (and results) follow:

```
--> mfile2sci
 ans  =

    []

  ****** Beginning of mfile2sci() session ******
  File to convert: C:/Users/User/Downloads/WTF_new.m
  Result file path: C:/Users/User/DOWNLO~1/
  Recursive mode: OFF
  Only double values used in M-file: NO
  Verbose mode: 3
  Generate formatted code: NO
  M-file reading...
  M-file reading: Done
  Syntax modification...
  Syntax modification: Done
  File contains no instruction, no translation made...
  ****** End of mfile2sci() session ******
```

Comment: What is the value of Mmax ?

Comment: Oops, looks like I didn't grab the first line when i copy/pasted. Mmax = 15. Editing original post to include this

Comment: That file should run as-is in Octave.

Comment: I tried your original script after adding Mmax=15 in order to compare the results, with the manually converted script. I got the following error : Index exceeds the number of array elements (2).

Error in test2 (line 65)
                    xhat(indx(j))=coeff(j);

Comment: If even the Matlab script does not work it will be difficult to test the converted script.

Comment: The issue isn't whether the converted script works or not; it's that the mfile2sci command doesn't give me a converted script in the first place. I get the same error with a basic hello, world file for matlab.

Comment: The indentation of the original code is very bad. Likely 2 "end" are missing to close the 2 first nested "for"... To be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the foo.m file one has to enter

```
 mfile2sci <path>/foo.m
```

where  stands for the path of the directoty where foo.m is. The result is written in /foo.sci

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. When running that command I get the same message as in the original post. Using the GUI implementation of mfile2sci, the output file only contains  7 lines taken seemingly at random from the m file. The mfile2sci C:\.....\foo.m command doesn't return any output file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ```` at the begining of each line, the conversion will proceed normally ?. However, don't expect to obtain a working .sci file as the m2sci converter is (to me) still an experimental tool !

Comment: Ah, sorry, the ```` are not in the original .m file. When I copy/pasted my code in the stackoverflow question field, it displayed as a solid block with no formatting. The instructions said to use ```` to keep formatting, but it didn't delete them in the post. The interface has changed slightly since I last posted here. 

Bummer that m2sci doesn't seem to work :( I can manually substitute functions, but again, I have hundreds of .m files and really don't want to manually scour each one.